# apt-get install stuck at "Unpacking wine..."

Tags: apt, updates, wine, package-management, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and using an ordinary `apt-get install playonlinux` command to have it installed.

However, it is always getting stuck at (i.e. doesn't do anything further):

```
Preparing to unpack .../wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6-amd64 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) over (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
```

I have already tried running `apt-get [auto]clean`, `apt-get update`, also tried manually downloading from a different mirror and installing the package manually with `dpkg -i`, but all those attempts had the same outcome: stuck at `Unpacking wine1.6-amd64`.

Running `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a` due to the broken earlier installation attempt didn't help either. And now looks like the 2 wine packages on my system are in a very inconsistent shape:

```
thatGuy@Neverland:/var$ dpkg -l wine1.6*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-==============================================================================
iU  wine1.6                              1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4        amd64                   Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)
iHR wine1.6-amd64                        1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4        amd64                   (no description available)
rHR wine1.6-i386                         1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4        i386                    Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
```

Please help saving my bacon!

Thanks,
- R

Comment: Others things I've tried to circumvent the problem: rename the package to something simpler (e.g. wine1.6.deb) and install it. No luck there either.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a couple of hours on this until I found two previous threads where Sophos AV antivirus interfered with this unpacking without throwing up a warning.  Turning off live scanning, install Wine, then turn live scanning back on.

To turn it OFF: `sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savconfig set LiveProtection false`
To turn it ON : `sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savconfig set LiveProtection true`

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Ubuntu Forums - Unable to remove bad package installed from .deb](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1608698):

Let's modify the post to match your package:

1. Can you print the output of cat `/var/lib/dpkg/status | grep wine`?
2. `dpkg -P wine`
3. If this does not work: `dpkg -L wine`. This will list the files that wine uses.
4. Navigate to: `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.
5. Delete the file: wine.postrm, possibly wine-version.postrm
6. Run `apt-get remove --purge wine`
7. Remove all files and directories you found with `dpkg -L`.
8. Then run `apt-get update`.